# Trying to move widget position

Tags: flutter, dart

I just started learning dart(flutter) using Angela's course, but unfortunately it seems outdated so I cant seem to understand how to do this from there.

I need to move the title to the center (I have it on the right just to test it, but even that didn't work):

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("I am Rich",textAlign:TextAlign.right),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title property in the AppBar is centred by default. If you don't want that, you can set the 'centreTitle' property of the AppBar to false.

```
appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Your title"),
  ),
```

[image: Title in the centre]

```
appBar: AppBar(
    centerTitle: false,
    title: Text("Your title"),
  ),
```

[image: title to the left]

On devices with text direction left to right, the title will be to the left it centerTitle is set it to false. If you really want to set it to the right, wrap your title widget with a Row Widget and set its mainAxisAlignment to mainAxisAlignment.end like this:

```
appBar: AppBar(
    title: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        Text("Your title"),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On `AppBar` use `centerTitle: true,`

```
AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Chalo"),
      ),
```

does it solve on your case?